# JVectorMap: change map on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have three buttons in `index.html`. When I click on them I need the jvectormap in a different file `map.html` to change. The js code is in another file, `map.js`.

**Example**
If I click on:

```
<button type="button" id="world">World Map</button>
<button type="button" id="Europe">Europe Map</button>
```

Should change the `map` property value to either `world_mill_en` or `eu_mill_en`

```
map = new jvm.Map({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
})
```

Is it possible to do this? I was not able to find an answer or figure it out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a query string from one html page to another .For Eg

In index.html

```
<button type="button" id="world" onclick="window.location.href='map.html?map=world_mill_en'">World Map</button>
```

In map.html, get the query string value and use it in the required place.